# Jquery - Set default value to dynamically generated form select

Tags: jquery, ajax

I get a dynamically generated select options through ajax and I would like to set it to a default value and to do this I did it this way

```
$.ajax ({
    url: ..,
    data: ...,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "html",
    cache: false
}).done ( function ( data ) {
    console.log('success callback 1');
    $( 'body' ).find( '[data-html-select="mark"]' ).html( data );
}).done(function() {
    console.log('success callback 2');
    $( 'body' ).find( '[data-html-select="mark"]' ).val( 10 );
})
```

ajax returned data

```
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
...
```

html

```
 <select data-html-select="mark">
     <option value=""></option>
 </select>
```

Unfortunately I realized that sometimes the default value is not set.
I think the problem is due to the fact that when the value is set the options have not yet been fully loaded.
To solve I tried in these ways without success.

```
}).done ( function ( data ) {
    $( 'body' ).find( '[data-html-select="mark"]' ).html( data );
}).done(function() {
    $( 'body' ).find( '[data-html-select="mark"]' ).val( 10 );
})
```

or

```
$( 'body' ).find( '[data-html-select="mark"]' ).html( data ).val( 10 );
```

Comment: You should probably do the `select` rendering on the client-side and have your server return the selected index instead of the HTML itself.

Comment: Why are there two `.done()` chained to the original promise? You can wrap everything in the first callback. Also, what is `data`?

Comment: @Terry I think the chained `.done()` callback was his attempt in trying to "set" the selected index once it's *ready*. First `.done` for loading the HTML, the second is for setting the index. Although I believe that's not how it works.

Comment: Using `.html(data).val(10)` should work fine inside one `done()` assuming there is an option with that value. Provide sample of html returned

Comment: I edit my question

Comment: As @charlietfl said there is no obvious reason from what you've posted as to why it apparently doesn't work. You also don't need two callbacks; that will have no benefit over a single callback. Can you reproduce this in a Fiddle?

Comment: The basics shown work fine here http://plnkr.co/edit/kQF7GOGWCWMlhzmzRgsW?p=preview